# Tkinter GUI freeze when running method (How to add threading?)

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Sorry for bothering you, but I would like to ask for help. My tkinter application freezes when I'm calling my Neural_network method because it interrupts the main loop. I tried to add threading, but it did not work as intended. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

```
class Toplevel1:
def __init__(self, top=None):
    def neural_network(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5):
        #NEURAL NETWORK STUFF GOING ON HERE
        print(round(prediction.item(0)))
        if round(prediction.item(0)) == 1: self.Label1_6.configure(text='''Malignant''', foreground="red")
        else: self.Label1_6.configure(text='''Benign''', foreground="green")

    def call_neural(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5):
        self.Label1_6.configure(text='''Please wait...''', foreground="black")
        root.after(10000, neural_network(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5))

    def analytics():
        try:
            float(self.Entry1_3.get())
            float(self.Entry1_4.get())
            float(self.Entry1_5.get())
            float(self.Entry1_6.get())
            float(self.Entry1_7.get())
            p1 = (float(self.Entry1_3.get()) - 6.981) / (21.129)
            p2 = (float(self.Entry1_4.get()) - 43.79) / (144.71)
            p3 = (float(self.Entry1_5.get()) - 143.5) / (2357.5)
            p4 = (float(self.Entry1_6.get()) - 0.01938) / (0.32602)
            p5 = (float(self.Entry1_7.get()) - 0) / (0.4268)
            if 0 <= p1 <= 1 and 0 <= p2 <= 1 and 0 <= p3 <= 1 and 0 <= p4 <= 1 and 0 <= p5 <= 1: call_neural(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
            else:  self.Label1_6.configure(text='''Error: Out of bounds''')
        except ValueError:
            self.Label1_6.configure(text='''Please fill all fields''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from the question what do you mean by "*I tried to add threading, but it did not work as intended.*"

Anyways please check this post:
http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html

It explains about various methods(including the threading method) which can be used to keep your GUI responsive while doing other work. Hope it helps.